# Count things with a dictonary without permanently check for existance?

Tags: c#, dictionary, default

Today I use code like this to count things:

```
Dictionary<string,int> wordCount = new Dictionary<string,int>();
if (!wordCount.ContainsKey(word))
{
    wordCount.Add(word, 0);
}
wordCount[word]++;
```

Is there a more elegant way to count things without permanently check existence?

I would like to do something like:

```
Dictionary<string,int> wordCount = new Dictionary<string,int>();
wordCount[word]++;
```

And values for the new key should automatically be initialized with a default value (0 for int for example).

Is there an elegant way to have this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define an extension method for dictionaries like this:

```
public static class DictionaryExtension
{
    public static void AddCount<T>(this Dictionary<T, int> dict, T key)
    {
        if (dict.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            dict[key]++;
        }
        else
        {
            dict[key] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
Dictionary<string, int> count = new Dictionary<string, int>();
count.AddCount("foo");
count.AddCount("bar");
count.AddCount("foo");
```

To go further, you could derive a new type from `Dictionary` and introduce a new indexer:

```
public class FancyDict<T> : Dictionary<T,int>
{
    public new int this[T key]
    {
        get => this.ContainsKey(key) ? base[key] : 0;
        set => base[key] = value;
    }
}
```

This makes it possible to use the `[]` syntax:

```
FancyDict<string> fancyCount = new FancyDict<string>();
fancyCount["foo"]++;
fancyCount["bar"]++;
fancyCount["foo"]++;

foreach (var key in fancyCount.Keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine(key + " : " + fancyCount[key]);
}
```

Comment: Cool idea. Would it also be possible to override the []-operator, to even hide the extension more to the user? So one could stay with the count["foo"]++ syntax.

Comment: It's indeed possible! - I added it to my answer.

Comment: Great. I extended it to                  return ContainsKey(key) ? base[key] : default( TValue);    One more question: can I modify the Dictionary typ directly without deriving?

Comment: It is not possible to "directly" modify an existing class/type. The one thing that comes closest is extension methods. But these cannot override existing methods, only extend the existing type.

Answer (score 2):

The `TryGetValue()` method will set the `out` parameter to its default value if the key is not present. You can use this to your advantage to simplify the code like this:

```cs
wordCount.TryGetValue(word, out int count);
wordCount[word] = count + 1;
```

That's about as simple as you're going to get, when you don't know what keys you're going to be using except by iterating through the data (obviously, if you did know the keys, you could initialize the dictionary with all the keys before you start counting).

You can, of course, always encapsulate any often-used code in an extension method or other abstraction, to further simplify the call site itself. The above explains how to simplify the *implementation*.